# How to calculate averages in PI DataLink

Tags: excel, osisoft

How to calculate the averages of the last 4 hours of the variable `FIC02` in the date of the cell `DATE`?

See below:

| DATE |  | FIC02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08-jan-08 06:30:00 |  | ? |
| 08-jan-08 13:30:00 |  | ? |
| 08-jan-08 20:30:00 |  | ? |

I'm using PI DataLink's 'Calculated data' function in Excel with:

`start time: 08-jan-08 06:30:00 - (4/24)`
`end time    08-jan-08 06:30:00`

The code used is below:
`=PIAdvCalcVal("FIC02";"'Planilha1'!$A$6 - (4/24)";Planilha1!$A$6;"average";"time-weighted";0;1;0;"")`

The following error message appears: *The time is invalid.*

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a time range

See below. I have a start time and 4h later an end time.

[image: Adv Calc]

If you need an hourly average over the same time range, then specify the optional "Time interval"
As an example I calculate an hourly (60m=60minutes, you can also write 1h) average over the same timespan

[image]

You can indeed make a calculation relative to a single time field. Just make sure the time format in excel is correct.

As you ca see both ways (start end time & end time - 5h) yields the same result,

[image]